# Can I receive what I send on a socket?

Tags: c, sockets, unix

I have a server that accepts connection from client and forks creating two processes: one reads from client using `recv()` and the other writes to client using `send()`. Both functions use the same file descriptor returned by `accept()`.

The client works similarly. It `connect()`'s to server and forks creating two processes: one reads from server using `recv()` and the other writes to server using `send()`. Both use the same file descriptor returned by `socket()`.

The socket domain is **AF_INET** and the type is **SOCK_STREAM**. I want the client to receive data from server and vice versa.

Can I receive what I send? For example: Can the server send a message and receive it so the client will never see it?

Comment: Please explain what you're trying to achieve in more detail. As it is, I don't see any point for the server to send anything if it doesn't want the client to receive it.

Comment: That's true. I want the client to receive data from server and vice versa.

Comment: The question is: Will it (always) work or may the client not receive the data?

Comment: A program or a process can be both client and server, and might even be its own client or server

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch can you elaborate how do these cases change my question?

Comment: Everything makes sense until the last sentence. Perhaps you can clarify your meaning there?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk I will try to explain in another way. Let's assume that server and client are two ends of a chat and server sends a message. I am wondering if with both server and client calling `recv()` on the same socket (obtained as explained in question), the server may `recv()` the same message it has just sent, then the message wouldn't be `recv()` by the client. That's not what we want in our chat.

Comment: Your basics are not clear. Server recv() reads the buffer kernel setup which effectively has data sent by the client. and server send() writes the data to kernel write buffer and kernel takes care of delivering it to client recv() buffer , So server recv() will not read back the same message , Dont worry ! And same goes with client.

Comment: No, that can't happen. The two directions are completely separate between peers A and B. When A `sends` something, only B can `recv` it, and vice-versa.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: Recommended reading: [*Advanced Linux Programming*](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/) then [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) then [tcp(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/tcp.7.html) and [sockets(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html) and [unix(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html). Follow hyperlinks there.